# Re-opening a closed post

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [List of all supported iOS versions for particular device models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76800620/list-of-all-supported-ios-versions-for-particular-device-models)

Should the above post be closed? How should I re-word my question if I want to know how people identify supported iOS versions/releases for Apple devices?

Comment: I guess your title is misleading you don’t want to ask "[a] list of …" but "how to get a list of …".

Comment: Corresponding to the closure notice your question is specifically seeking recommendations for an API endpoint. You can try asking on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) as it [might be ontopic there](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/716/are-web-api-recommendations-on-topic)

Answer (score 7):

No, I don't think this question should be closed as asking for offsite resources. It definitely reads like it does that at first glance, but if you take a second to think about it then it is a how-to question at heart.

But that's the problem - questions shouldn't require the reader to have to think about what is being asked exactly. When given a choice based on ambiguity in the question, curators on Stack Overflow will often choose to close quickly. That is a knee jerk response to the fact that the site gets thousands of new questions a day - closing and downvoting the unwanted questions quickly gives more breathing space for questions that are acceptable according to the site's standards and rules.

Great popularity is not without its costs and the price we have to pay is time - time spent polishing up questions and answers before posting their first version to the public eye so they shine and can't be misunderstood.

In this particular case, I would say the last paragraph asking

> Besides manually creating a matrix myself based on information in the
> Wikipedia (or other) links, is this information available publicly via
> an API endpoint or a CSV, JSON, XML, or other format which I can use
> in my code

is the problem, that is what makes the question read like you're asking for offsite resources. It is pretty much what Stack Overflow calls "fluff" - content which adds no value to the post and can even serve to derail it. The actual how-to question of what you need to do to programmatically solve the problem is enough. If that can be done with some kind of API or meta data file that is publicly available then an answer will tell you that. There is no need to sort of take potential answerers by the hand like that.

Comment: If that paragraph is removed, then I can see two possible kinds of answers. (a) I recommend this external resource (which would attract downvotes and low quality flags as being little more than a link to an off-site resource) and (b) a laborious explanation of how to create said matrix (which (i) the OP appears to already know how to do and (ii) probably means the question serves to be dinged as *needs more focus*)

Comment: @Gimby - Thanks for the feedback, I have now removed that paragraph.

Comment: So why should this question be closed, instead of just an answer that states "iOS does not offer this functionality"? What happens when another person comes along with the same question?

Comment: @GrahamReynolds I don't understand that question, I pretty clearly stated that my opinion is that it shouldn't be closed. The very first sentence even.

Comment: @GrahamReynolds — the question isn’t asking for support information for the device the code is running on. It’s asking for support information for each of a list of named devices. (I.e. even with the edit it is seeking a data source, not a solution to a programming problem).